# REMOTE_USER wit OAuth and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, oauth

I am trying to create some sort of restriction for my website.
This website will host certain documents that only Users authenticated on my support site can access. The site supports OAuth and what I need is to check, anytime a User access my content site, whether he is authenticated or not. If not, redirect or show an error message.

I have been suggested that it is possible that OAuth uses REMOTE_USER and therefore using it directly in my rewriterule.

How would I do that?

My first idea was to use rewriterule and, using some sort of OAuthLoginChecker.php, check whether the user is logged in or not (return true or false and act accordingly). Which way would it be best?

Comment: This answer depends on what library you use to authenticate a user for oauth.

Comment: I haven't used anything yet. I just know that the support site I use (Zendesk) has OAuth and I thought it would be useful to use it. So, go  on with your suggestion.